# Karate : repeat a request

Tags: karate

I want to repeat 6 times a post request of a scenario:

```
Given url <url>
And path 'toto'
And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + <token>
And request processData.signer1
When method post
Then status 201
```

I have seen the "repeat" method in the documentation, but I have the impression that it is not suitable for my case

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 feature files. Then you can do this:

```
* karate.repeat(3, () => karate.call('called.feature'))
```

Comment: It seems you have to do this if the function you are calling takes an argument, too.

For example, karate.repeat(3, fun) works, but karate.repeat(3, fun(x)) throws "not a JS function". karate.repeat(3, () -> fun(x)) does work.

Comment: @KeithTyler I suggest you take the help of someone who knows JS. the second arg here has to be a JS function not a JS statement (or constant or variable)